# org.json.JSONException: "JSON object not found in JSON array"

Tags: java, json

A very simple JSON like this (`response.getBody().toString()`):

```
{"per_page":50,"total":93,"last_page":2,"stars":[]}
```

Has some problems when I want to parse it:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.getBody()); // no error
System.out.println(object.getJSONObject("total")); // not found
```

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["total"] not found.

Other properties cannot be parsed either:

```
JSONArray startups = object.getJSONArray("stars");
```

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["stars"] not found.

---

The key is to hold the value of response.getBody()

```
String json = response.getBody().toString();
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets.

Comment: The code snippets look Ok so there must be an error in the other parts of the code.

Comment: I would rather create model to map that response and read the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String json = "{\"per_page\":50,\"total\":93,\"last_page\":2,\"stars\":[]}":

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (json);

JSONArray jsonArray  = jsonObect.getJSONArray("stars");

int perPage = jsonObject.getInt("per_page");
```

try like this...

Answer (score 3):

Inside object `total` is not `JSONObject` it is an `Int` value, that's why you code crashing.

So use this

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(object.getInt("total")));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(object.getJSONObject("total"));
```

Comment: Actually, because of the missing doublequotes, it might be a JsonNumber accessible using object.getJsonNumber("total"), but you are right about it not being an object.

Comment: It is actually an int. I tried getInt(), getString() and get(), same result

Comment: use `System.out.println(object.getInt("total")+"")`

Comment: before getting the value from object check the value is present or not. using object.has("total")

Answer (score 0):

In addition to earlier answer, to parse array, use `getJSONArray` as

```
JSONArray ja = jsonObj.getJSONArray("stars");
```

You can loop-over the array as:

```
for(int j=0; j<ja.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject json = ja.getJSONObject(j);
    // do same as before for string, int or other data types
}
```